# pyexcel save to Django model

Tags: python, django, pyexcel

Having difficulties understanding the documentation for interaction between `dest_initializer` and `dest_model`?

If I have a Django model like:

```
class MyModel(Model)
    file = FileField()
```

How can I write a file to **an instance** of this model?

```
instance = MyModel()

records = [OrderedDict([("Test Key", "Test Value")])]
pyexcel.save_as(
                records=records,
                dest_model=MyModel,
                ...... ?????? How to write to instance.field?
            )
```

Comment: I believe with ```pyexcel.save_as()``` you can save the entire excel row to a model, not to a FileField.

Comment: @Sumithran thanks, that is what I think so after reading deeper too. If you want, you can make that into an answer and I will accept it.